# Intel XDK using cordova plugin to detect incoming call

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, intel-xdk

Iam using Intel XDK to build a hybrid android application , im trying to use this cordova [plugin](https://github.com/renanoliveira/cordova-phone-call-trap) to detect incoming call.

In order to use this plugn in intel XDK , im using XDK UI project config window.

[image: xdk PhoneCallTrap]

i believe this is the right method to add the plugin , the issue is:

plugin is never added to project unless you build it.

and when using plugin js function , intel xdk doesnt recognize it , anyway i built the project and used following function :

```
PhoneCallTrap.onCall(function(state) {
    console.log("CHANGE STATE: " + state);

    switch (state) {
        case "RINGING":
            alert("Phone is ringing");
            break;
        case "OFFHOOK":
            console.log("Phone is off-hook");
            break;

        case "IDLE":
            console.log("Phone is idle");
            break;
    }
}); // xdk reports that 'PhoneCallTrap' is not defined. (W117)  PhoneCallTrap.onCall(function(state) {
```

on ringing no alert was fired , does anyone know what may the issue be ?

Comment: When you perform a build does the plugin ID show up in the build log? If so, that means the plugin _was_ included with the build. If not, something was not right regarding the build or plugin setup (your plugin import dialog looks correct).    Also, the Emulate, Test and Debug tabs cannot see any third-party plugins you add to the project, they can only see the "core" plugins that can be "checked" on the Project tab. You must build to debug an app that contains third-party plugins.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that third party plugins in the Intel XDK are only incorporated when you build your app.  The various test, emulate and debug environments provide the standard plugins, but it is tricky to build arbitrary plugins for those environments.

I tried building an Android app with the above plugin, and then installed the resulting apk on my phone, and it seemed to work as advertised.  One possible confusion might arise from the fact that as soon as the phone starts ringing, it switches to the phone app, so you may not notice the alert before that happens, though the alert is still there when I'm done with the phone and switch back to my app.

Comment: thanks for trying , actually it works for me now , i have should trigger actions on device ready , that is all.